# Is it safe to drive this car (pics; broken shock; negative camber)

Tags: shock-absorber, camber

Would it be safe and not cause further damage to the car if I were to drive it 1/4 mile on a dirt and somewhat bumpy road? (The towing company under my policy won't go on dirt roads.) I've been told that the issues is that the shock is broken.

[image]

Comment: Is the upper control arm broken also? If so, I don't think you will make it.

Comment: Safe is one thing. You could drive just about anything at 2mph *safely*. This, however, would probably not make it. As @cano stated ... where's the upper control arm? I see what might possibly part of it in the background behind shock, but that's some ugly damage. If you did drive it, the tire would be rubbing against the shock and what's left of the upper A-arm. Hopefully this isn't a front wheel drive vehicle (looks like a 4x4). If so, ensure you DO NOT have this in 4wd, nor that the front hubs are engaged (if you have to do so manually). This is just pure ugly.

Comment: What kind of tools do you have with you?

Comment: Do you have a trail jack? If so, I may have an idea for you, but it would take some ingenuity and perseverance to make it work.

Comment: Given the angle of the wheel and driveshaft I would not drive it. If the only thing broken is the shock absorber then why not take the new shock and the tools and a decent jack & stand and make a better than temporary repair where it is now - then take it to the shop to make sure all is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is the shock broken but the upper suspension control arm has collapsed too. Driving the vehicle would likely cause further damage to the tyre, CV unit & possibly front differential/bearings too as there is a lot of force being transferred through that drive shaft into the front diff with the upper control arm collapsed.

Unless you have some sort of trolly to place the front right of the vehicle on to, your only other option other than a front end lift is to put a lot of weight onto the rear left of the vehicle to help unload the right front wheel. Then perhaps an attempt at moving forward might be possible, but do it very slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Is it safe? Safe is relative, but you won't be going far in that car anyway - it's broken as broken can be.

I assume you're getting the car towed to a garage for repairs. I'd suggest getting a pair of front shock absorbers online, and then paying for a mobile mechanic to come out and install them for you. That should get it moving again, and the mechanic will be able to tell you what else is broken. After those repairs, you will be safe to drive it to a garage for an alignment.